# How to get leaderboard rank using SteamWork.Net?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, leaderboard, steamworks-api

I have a unity project and I have added SteamWork.net wrapper to my project  , 
and In that project I do leaderboard upload / setting statistics etc

I have no clue how to get rank in a leaderboard ?

Let's say I have a leaderboard called "Highscore" , Then how do I get my rank in leaderboard ?

Comment: Shouldn't the rank be the same as the position of each "Highscore" when you order the data by "Highscore"? Or you want a separate rank system? Please give more details about your question.

Comment: Yeah , It's the position,  How do you get position ?

Comment: I do not know if you can all users using the API. However what I do know is that you can get your friends.... The cleanest way to do so is storing the score data in your leaderboard table and pull from it. Makes sense?

Comment: Did you mean I should read from " LeaderboardScoreUploaded_t " ?

Comment: Read all entries order by "LeaderboardScoreUploaded_t"  (in desc) and then you'd have the rank ready.

Comment: Actually not ,It's not the solution , There should be a better way, 

I can directly read new rank from LeaderboardScoreUploaded_t as it's a call result.  But I can read it only when I upload a value. 
I need a solution where I can read to position without downloading entire leaderboard. There should be something

Comment: Hi Steve, I am also in need of this answer. Did you find anything on this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a method for getting scores for specific steam users.
So we can just send the csteamID of the local user and get the details as shown below.

```
CSteamID[] Users = { SteamUser.GetSteamID() }; // Local user steam id
SteamAPICall_t handle = SteamUserStats.DownloadLeaderboardEntriesForUsers(m_SteamLeaderboard, Users, Users.Length);
.
.
```